# An infinite dimensional Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and $F$ a proper subspace of $E$.
Let $R: E → F ⊊ E$.

We know that $R$ is linear, injective and that $R(E) ≠ F$ and $R(E)$ is closed.

1) I want to prove that if $R(E) ≠ F$, then there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that $\|Rx\|≥ c \|x\|$.
This prove that $R$ is not the limit of a sequence in the linear group $GL(E)$.

2) Now I want to prove that if $\|Rx\|≥ c \|x\|$ for any $x$, $\|T_n^{-1} x\| ≤ c/2 \|x\|$.

Comment: (1) use the open mapping theorem.  (2) What is $T_n$?

Comment: We suppose that is the sequence in the linear group and we suppose that is converging to the application we define above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Learn Mathjax - Nate has edited for you.

Comment: @user334732: It was actually Bernard who added the Mathjax.